# Is there any equivalent to use something like MappingManager on datastax java client 4.x

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

In datastax 3.x there used to be mappingManager. We used it to get different mappers using com.datastax.driver.mapping.MappingManager.

Can someone help me, What can I use in datastax 4.x.

Comment: what are you trying to finally achieve here with DataStax Java Driver 4.x? Could you elaborate and give some additional context here? Maybe an example that is working with DataStax Java Driver 3.x series? There is also a great examples resource [here](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/java-cassandra-driver-from3x-to4x) that you could check out for.